# Why do I get a Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

```
const getList = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { userId, name } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).populate({
      path: 'lists',
      populate: { path: 'books' },
    });

    if (!user) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
    }

    let list = user.lists.find((list) => list.listName === name);

    if (!list) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'List does not exist' });
    }

    res.status(200).json(list);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

When I test the route on postman I get a successful response(the list). However I get this error on the client.

Comment: Because you're not returning when you're sending the response. Each of those `res.status....` lines should be `return res.status.....` so the code _stops_ rather than happily carrying on trying to send up to three responses for the same request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop further execution of your function with either a `return` or `if/else` or some flow control when you send a response so the rest of the function's code doesn't continue to run.

Change this:

```
if (!user) {
  res.status(400).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
}
```

to this:

```
if (!user) {
  res.status(400).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
  return;
}
```

and this:

```
if (!list) {
  res.status(400).json({ error: 'List does not exist' });
}
```

to this:

```
if (!list) {
  res.status(400).json({ error: 'List does not exist' });
  return;
}
```

Here's a fixed version, along with an addition to send an error response in your `catch` handler as you must ALWAYS send some response to every incoming request.  And, you do not need to do `.status(200)` as that is the default status.

```
const getList = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { userId, name } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findById(userId).populate({
            path: 'lists',
            populate: { path: 'books' },
        });

        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
            return;
        }

        const list = user.lists.find((list) => list.listName === name);

        if (!list) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: 'List does not exist' });
            return;
        }

        res.json(list);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```